# Avoid rerendering every component in list while updating only one in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

I have a simple chat app using Firebase v9, with these components from parent to child in this hierarchical order: `ChatSection`, `Chat`, `ChatLine`, `EditMessage`.

I have a custom hook named `useChatService` holding the list of `messages` in state, the hook is called in `ChatSection`, the hook returns the `messages` and I pass them from `ChatSection` in a prop to `Chat`, then I loop through `messages` and create a `ChatLine` component for every message.

I can click the `Edit` button in front of each message, it shows the `EditMessage` component so I can edit the text, then when I press "Enter", the function `updateMessage` gets executed and updates the message in the db, but then every single `ChatLine` gets rerendered again, which is a problem as the list gets bigger.

**EDIT 2:** I've completed the code to make a working example with Firebase v9 so you can visualize the rerenders I'm talking about after every (add, edit or delete) of a message. I'm using ReactDevTools Profiler to track rerenders.

- Here is the full updated code: [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/icy-meadow-xv8um)
- Also deployed on: [Netlify](https://csb-bg7i7.netlify.app/)

`ChatSection.js`:

```
import useChatService from "../hooks/useChatService";
import { useEffect } from "react";
import Chat from "./Chat";
import NoChat from "./NoChat";
import ChatInput from "./ChatInput";

const ChatSection = () => {
  let unsubscribe;
  const { getChatAndUnsub, messages } = useChatService();

  useEffect(() => {
    const getChat = async () => {
      unsubscribe = await getChatAndUnsub();
    };

    getChat();

    return () => {
      unsubscribe?.();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.length ? <Chat messages={messages} /> : <NoChat />}
      <p>ADD A MESSAGE</p>
      <ChatInput />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatSection;
```

`Chat.js`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ChatLine from "./ChatLine";
import useChatService from "../hooks/useChatService";

const Chat = ({ messages }) => {
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
  const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(null);

  const { updateMessage, deleteMessage } = useChatService();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {messages.map((line) => (
        <ChatLine
          key={line.id}
          line={line}
          editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          editingId={line.id === editingId ? editingId : null}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          updateMessage={updateMessage}
          deleteMessage={deleteMessage}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

`ChatInput`:

```
import { useState } from "react";
import useChatService from "../hooks/useChatService";

const ChatInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const { addMessage } = useChatService();

  return (
    <textarea
      onKeyPress={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault();
          addMessage(inputValue);
          setInputValue("");
        }
      }}
      placeholder="new message..."
      onChange={(e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      value={inputValue}
      autoFocus
    />
  );
};

export default ChatInput;
```

`ChatLine.js`:

```
import EditMessage from "./EditMessage";
import { memo } from "react";

const ChatLine = ({
  line,
  editValue,
  setEditValue,
  editingId,
  setEditingId,
  updateMessage,
  deleteMessage,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      {editingId !== line.id ? (
        <>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>{line.id}: </span>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>[{line.displayName}]</span>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>{line.message}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setEditingId(line.id);
              setEditValue(line.message);
            }}
          >
            EDIT
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              deleteMessage(line.id);
            }}
          >
            DELETE
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <EditMessage
          editValue={editValue}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          editingId={editingId}
          updateMessage={updateMessage}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(ChatLine);
```

`EditMessage.js`:

```
import { memo } from "react";

const EditMessage = ({
  editValue,
  setEditValue,
  editingId,
  setEditingId,
  updateMessage,
}) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            // prevent textarea default behaviour (line break on Enter)
            e.preventDefault();
            // updating message in DB
            updateMessage(editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId);
          }
        }}
        onChange={(e) => setEditValue(e.target.value)}
        value={editValue}
        autoFocus
      />
      <button
        onClick={() => {
          setEditingId(null);
          setEditValue(null);
        }}
      >
        CANCEL
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(EditMessage);
```

`useChatService.js`:

```
import { useCallback, useState } from "react";
import {
  collection,
  onSnapshot,
  orderBy,
  query,
  serverTimestamp,
  updateDoc,
  doc,
  addDoc,
  deleteDoc,
} from "firebase/firestore";
import { db } from "../firebase/firebase-config";

const useChatService = () => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  /**
   * Get Messages
   *
   * @returns {Promise<Unsubscribe>}
   */
  const getChatAndUnsub = async () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("createdAt"));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
        const entry = doc.data();

        return {
          id: doc.id,
          message: entry.message,
          createdAt: entry.createdAt,
          updatedAt: entry.updatedAt,
          uid: entry.uid,
          displayName: entry.displayName,
          photoURL: entry.photoURL,
        };
      });

      setMessages(data);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  };

  /**
   * Memoized using useCallback
   */
  const updateMessage = useCallback(
    async (editValue, setEditValue, editingId, setEditingId) => {
      const message = editValue;
      const id = editingId;

      // resetting state as soon as we press Enter
      setEditValue("");
      setEditingId(null);

      try {
        await updateDoc(doc(db, "messages", id), {
          message,
          updatedAt: serverTimestamp(),
        });
      } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
      }
    },
    []
  );

  const addMessage = async (inputValue) => {
    if (!inputValue) {
      return;
    }
    const message = inputValue;

    const messageData = {
      // hardcoded photoURL, uid, and displayName for demo purposes
      photoURL:
        "https://lh3.googleusercontent.com/a/AATXAJwNw_ECd4OhqV0bwAb7l4UqtPYeSrRMpVB7ayxY=s96-c",
      uid: keyGen(),
      message,
      displayName: "John Doe",
      createdAt: serverTimestamp(),
      updatedAt: null,
    };

    try {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), messageData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  };

  /**
   * Memoized using useCallback
   */
  const deleteMessage = useCallback(async (idToDelete) => {
    if (!idToDelete) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "messages", idToDelete));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  const keyGen = () => {
    const s = "abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
    return Array(20)
      .join()
      .split(",")
      .map(function () {
        return s.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * s.length));
      })
      .join("");
  };

  return {
    messages,
    getChatAndUnsub,
    updateMessage,
    addMessage,
    deleteMessage,
  };
};

export default useChatService;
```

When a message gets updated using `updateMessage` method, I only need the affected `ChatLine` to rerender (same for add & delete), not every single `ChatLine` in the list, while keeping the `messages` state passed from `ChatSection` to `Chat`, I understand that `ChatSection` & `Chat` should rerender, but not every `ChatLine` in the list. (Also `ChatLine` is memoized)

EDIT 1: I guess the problem is with `setMessages(data)` in `useChatService.js`, but I thought React will only rerender the edited line because I already provided the `key={line.id}` when looping through `messages` in `Chat` component, but I have no idea how to fix this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Prelude

It seems that several of your questions lately have revolved around trying to prevent React component rerenders. This is fine and well, but don't spend too much time prematurely optimizing. React runs quite well out-of-the-box.

Regarding `memo` HOC and optimizing performance, even the [docs](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-api.html#reactmemo) state outright:

> This method only exists as a performance optimization. Do not rely on
> it to “prevent” a render, as this can lead to bugs.

This means React may still rerender a component if it needs to. I believe mapping the `messages` array is one of these cases. When the `messages` state updates it's a new array, and so it must be rerendered. React's reconciliation needs to rerender the array and the each element of the array, but it may not need to go any deeper.

You could test this by adding a memoized child component to `ChatLine` and watch as even though `ChatLine` is wrapped in `memo` HOC that it is still rerendered while the memoized child is not.

```
const Child = memo(({ id }) => {
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log('Child rendered', id); // <-- doesn't log when messages updates
  })
  return <>Child: {id}</>;
});
```

...

```
const ChatLine = (props) => {
  ...

  useEffect(() => {
    console.log("Chatline rendered", line.id); // <-- logs when messages updates
  });

  return (
    <div>
      ...
          <Child id={line.id} />
      ...
    </div>
  );
};

export default memo(ChatLine);
```

The takeaway here should be that you shouldn't prematurely optimize. Tools like memoization and virtualization should only be looked at if you find an *actual* performance issue and have properly benchmarked/audited performance.

You shouldn't also "over-optimize" either. The React app I develop for a client I work with we did this early on thinking we were saving ourselves time but eventually over time (and as we've gained familiarity with React hooks) we've ripped out most or nearly all of our "optimizations" as they ended up not really saving us much and add more complexity. We eventually found our performance bottlenecks that had more to do with our architecture and component composition than it did with the # of components rendered in lists.

## Suggested Solution

So you were using the `useChatService` custom hook in several components but as written each hook was its own instance and providing its own copy of the `messages` state and other various callbacks. This is why you had to pass the `messages` state as a prop from `ChatSection` to `Chat`. Here I suggest to move the `messages` state and callbacks into a React context so each `useChatService` hook "instance" can provide the ***same*** context value.

### useChatService

(*could probably be renamed since more than just a hook now*)

Create a context:

```
export const ChatServiceContext = createContext({
  messages: [],
  updateMessage: () => {},
  addMessage: () => {},
  deleteMessage: () => {}
});
```

Create a context provider:

`getChatAndUnsub` wasn't awaiting anything so there was no reason to declare it `async`. Memoize all the callbacks to add, update, and delete messages.

```
const ChatServiceProvider = ({ children }) => {
  const [messages, setMessages] = useState([]);

  const getChatAndUnsub = () => {
    const q = query(collection(db, "messages"), orderBy("createdAt"));

    const unsubscribe = onSnapshot(q, (snapshot) => {
      const data = snapshot.docs.map((doc, index) => {
        const entry = doc.data();

        return { .... };
      });

      setMessages(data);
    });

    return unsubscribe;
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    const unsubscribe = getChatAndUnsub();

    return () => {
      unsubscribe();
    };
  }, []);

  const updateMessage = useCallback(async (message, id) => {
    try {
      await updateDoc(doc(db, "messages", id), {
        message,
        updatedAt: serverTimestamp()
      });
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  const addMessage = useCallback(async (message) => {
    if (!message) {
      return;
    }

    const messageData = { .... };

    try {
      await addDoc(collection(db, "messages"), messageData);
    } catch (e) {
      console.log(e);
    }
  }, []);

  const deleteMessage = useCallback(async (idToDelete) => {
    if (!idToDelete) {
      return;
    }
    try {
      await deleteDoc(doc(db, "messages", idToDelete));
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  }, []);

  const keyGen = () => { .... };

  return (
    <ChatServiceContext.Provider
      value={{
        messages,
        updateMessage,
        addMessage,
        deleteMessage
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </ChatServiceContext.Provider>
  );
};

export default ChatServiceProvider;
```

Create the `useChatService` hook:

```
export const useChatService = () => useContext(ChatServiceContext);
```

### Provide the Chat service to the app

index.js

```
import ChatServiceProvider from "./hooks/useChatService";

ReactDOM.render(
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ChatServiceProvider>
      <App />
    </ChatServiceProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,
  document.getElementById("root")
);
```

### ChatSection

Use the `useChatService` hook to consume the `messages` state.

```
const ChatSection = () => {
  const { messages } = useChatService();

  return (
    <div>
      {messages.length ? <Chat /> : <NoChat />}
      <p>ADD A MESSAGE</p>
      <ChatInput />
    </div>
  );
};

export default ChatSection;
```

### Chat

Remove the editing state and setters (*more on this later*). Use the `useChatService` hook to consume the `messages` state.

```
const Chat = () => {
  const { messages } = useChatService();

  return (
    <div>
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {messages.map((line) => (
        <ChatLine key={line.id} line={line} />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

### ChatLine

Move the editing state here. Instead of an `editingId` state use a boolean toggle for an edit mode. Encapsulate the edit id in the `updateMessage` callback from the context. Manage ***all*** the editing state here locally, don't pass the state values and setter as callbacks for another component to call. Note that the `EditMessage` component API was updated.

```
const ChatLine = ({ line }) => {
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
  const [isEditing, setIsEditing] = useState(false);

  const { updateMessage, deleteMessage } = useChatService();

  return (
    <div>
      {!isEditing ? (
        <>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>{line.id}: </span>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>[{line.displayName}]</span>
          <span style={{ marginRight: "20px" }}>{line.message}</span>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              setIsEditing(true);
              setEditValue(line.message);
            }}
          >
            EDIT
          </button>
          <button
            onClick={() => {
              deleteMessage(line.id);
            }}
          >
            DELETE
          </button>
        </>
      ) : (
        <EditMessage
          value={editValue}
          onChange={setEditValue}
          onSave={() => {
            // updating message in DB
            updateMessage(editValue, line.id);
            setEditValue("");
            setIsEditing(false);
          }}
          onCancel={() => setIsEditing(false)}
        />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};
```

Here you can use the `memo` HOC. You can further hint to React that *maybe* this component shouldn't rerender if the line id remains equal, but recall that this doesn't completely prevent the component from being rerendered. It's only a hint that maybe React can bail on rerenders.

```
export default memo(ChatLine, (prev, next) => {
  return prev.line.id === next.line.id;
});
```

### EditMessage

Just proxy the props to their respective props of the `textarea` and `button`. In other words, let `ChatLine` maintain the state it needs.

```
const EditMessage = ({ value, onChange, onSave, onCancel }) => {
  return (
    <div>
      <textarea
        onKeyPress={(e) => {
          if (e.key === "Enter") {
            // prevent textarea default behaviour (line break on Enter)
            e.preventDefault();
            onSave();
          }
        }}
        onChange={(e) => onChange(e.target.value)}
        value={value}
        autoFocus
      />
      <button type="button" onClick={onCancel}>
        CANCEL
      </button>
    </div>
  );
};

export default EditMessage;
```

### ChatInput

Consume `addMessage` from the `useChatService` hook. I don't think much changed here but including anyway for completeness' sake.

```
const ChatInput = () => {
  const [inputValue, setInputValue] = useState("");
  const { addMessage } = useChatService();

  return (
    <textarea
      onKeyPress={(e) => {
        if (e.key === "Enter") {
          e.preventDefault();
          addMessage(inputValue);
          setInputValue("");
        }
      }}
      placeholder="new message..."
      onChange={(e) => {
        setInputValue(e.target.value);
      }}
      value={inputValue}
      autoFocus
    />
  );
};

export default ChatInput;
```

[image: Edit avoid-rerendering-every-component-in-list-while-updating-only-one-in-react]

Comment: One last question if I may. Say I consume a context in `Chat` component, and I need something from the context in a child component `ChatLine` too. Should I use it in `Chat` and pass what I need as props from `Chat` to `ChatLine`, or should I consume it again in `ChatLine`? Which is better, in term of logic & performance.

Comment: @Dwix Since `Chat` is the direct parent of `ChatLine` I would say it's a wash between passing a prop from the context and just consuming it from the context in `ChatLine`. Since `ChatLine` is already using the chat service hook though it makes it easier to decouple the components. The React context API mainly serves to fix the issue of "props drilling" so you don't need to explicitly pass props down from Ancestor through all intermediate children to a Descendent. It's not for performance, per se, but certainly makes the code easier to work with and maintain.

Answer (score 2):

On the component `Chat.js` in the `.map` avoid to pass complex object as a props to the mapped component (in this case `ChatLine.js`

- You are passing as a props `line={line}`
- when you update the Message, React do not will know What Message was Changed and will re-render all `line`

##### solution to try

- try pass to `ChatLine.js` props like `lineId={line.id}`, `lineMessage={line.message}`, `lineDisplayName={line.displayName}`...
- Pass just `Primitives` to props .. like **strings, numbers, bools**

This happen because React just compare **shallow** objects

Answer (score 1):

Wrap ChatLine inside React.memo, it will stop multiple rereders.

**NOTE:** Update areEqual function according to your usecase.

```
import { useState } from "react";
import ChatLine from "./ChatLine";
import useChatService from "../hooks/useChatService";

function areEqual(prevProps, nextProps) {
  /*
  return true if passing nextProps to render would return
  the same result as passing prevProps to render,
  otherwise return false
  */
  return prevProps.line === nextProps.line;
}
const ChatLineMemo = React.memo(ChatLine, areEqual);

const Chat = ({ messages }) => {
  const [editValue, setEditValue] = useState("");
  const [editingId, setEditingId] = useState(null);

  const { updateMessage, deleteMessage } = useChatService();


  return (
    <div>
      <p>MESSAGES :</p>
      {messages.map((line) => (
        <ChatLineMemo
          key={line.id}
          line={line}
          editValue={line.id === editingId ? editValue : ""}
          setEditValue={setEditValue}
          editingId={line.id === editingId ? editingId : null}
          setEditingId={setEditingId}
          updateMessage={updateMessage}
          deleteMessage={deleteMessage}
        />
      ))}
    </div>
  );
};

export default Chat;
```

Comment: Yes I have already `ChatLine` wrapped in memo, and I can't succeed in implementing `areEqual(prevProps, nextProps)` successfully, even with `prevProps.line === nextProps.line` it's not working, you can test it yourself and see.

Comment: @Dwix One more thing you can try, wrap function to useCallback and then pass to ChatLineMemo.

Comment: I did, but that didn't change anything. I have to use the proper conditions in `areEqual` function, but I couldn't do it correctly. do you think you can help me fix this specific case?

Comment: `return prevProps.line === nextProps.line;` line is string or object. if object us line.msg

Answer (score 0):

This is what I think, You are passing `Messages` in `ChatSection` and that means that when `Messages` get updated `ChatSection` will rerender and all its children will rerender too.

So here is my idea remove `Messages` from `ChatSection` and only add it in `Chat`.

You already using `useChatService` in Chat so adding `Messages` there should be better.

Try this and gets back too us if it working.

If still not as you like it to be there is also other way we could fix it.

But you have to create a working example for us so we could have a look and make small changes.

Comment: I need to pass `messages` from `ChatSection` to `Chat`, because I'll be performing a check later, if messages are empty I won't even render `Chat`, I'll render another component. And yes when we `setMessages`, `ChatSection` & `Chat` rerender, which is normal, but I don't want all the list of `ChatLine` components to rerender because I've memoized the `ChatLine` component, and added the `key` prop while looping through them in `Chat`. So I'd like to know why this isn't working and how to only rerender the line we're updating, or adding..

Comment: You have to understand that when `setMessages` changed you rerender `ChatSection & Chat` and so all saved keys will be removed from the memory. it works like that. and the scroll will reset. if you have a working example, will could try and use other means to fix this.

Comment: Hi, I've updated the code and provided a fully working example hooked with Firebase. I edited the post and adde the links to CodeSandbox & Netlify. Thanks.

Comment: As far as I see it is working fine. you should create a pagination instead as that could handle the increase amount of data. Should i create one for you as an answer?

Comment: It's not about it working or not or pagination, what I'd like to do is only rerender the affected `ChatLine` instead of all the lines in the list each time we add, update or delete one of them.

Comment: It is working fine as far as I see it, I do not see a problem there. Could you show me the problem with your component.

Comment: An easy way to test it: I added `console.log("rendered")` in `ChatLine` component, and I added a new message in chat, then `rendered` is displayed 7 times because I added a 7th message to the list, so all the messages have been rerendered even though 6 of them didn't change. I do not want the lines who didn't change to rerender, that's the whole point of my question.

Comment: That is how react  work, As long as you inc useState in the return value and that useState variable / property changed, it will rerender the whole thing and it is normal. Now lets me see the problem. even if you rerender 1000 rows it will be quite fast. See there is noway to avoid rerendering those as long as you use React. If the problem you have is that is to slow rendering I do not see that now. And even if that is true you could create a pagination system. So tell me something I could do other then changing how react work:)

Comment: I appreciate you wanting to help, but it's not simply how React works, there are ways to control rerenders, that's why we have `memo` for example, by default it does a shallow comparison of the props in `ChatLine`, that's why the rerenders are happening right now, but I'll need to take advantage of the second argument of `memo()` which is a function having `(prevProps, nextProps)` as args, but I just can't figure out how to successfully implement it in my case yet. I'm also waiting for other suggestions, maybe there are better solutions.

Comment: I see that but you are having a problem for nothing. there is not an issue with the component right now. But well do as you see fit